# Crystal Reports 11 deployment with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create a web based report viewing page. Its working fine locally, but when i deploy it to client's web server it does not run and it gives error that crystal reports 10.5 components are missing. Client told me that  server have crystal reports 11 installed.

Now my question is, is there a way i can change assembly version from web.config to use version 11 of crystal reports?

Answer (score 5):

We usually just install the Crystal Reports Redistributable for 2008 where ever we need to install our applications.

It can usually be found in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5 directory

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to redirect the assembly version to CR 11. This link gives the full info for assembly binding redirection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try re-adding the references to the Crystal DLLs in your project?  Crystal 11 is not *directly* compatible with VS2008, so you may need to find the DLLs manually (try c:\windows\assembly\GAC and c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL).  After your project has been updated to use the 11.* DLLs, this should work on the client's machine.

FWIW -- the Crystal 10.5 DLLs you are referencing in your project now are most likely the DLLs for Crystal Basic 2008 (the version that comes with .NET).

Another option to guarantee the client has the DLLs would be to include the Crystal XIR2 merge modules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very reliably informed that the differing versions of Crystal are designed to sit side by side to the point that if you build against 10.5 (as ships with VS 2008), then you have to have the 10.5 binaries there (Redistributables should be under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` ).

Alternately, as the client has CR11 installed, you could install that on your dev boxes, and build against that -- at which point you'll find their side-by-side support fails slightly and all your other projects run the risk of being upgraded to v11.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal XI will be best suited for you. It supports classic ASP and VB. Probably, you will not even need much code change.